# django error cannot import name 'RemovedInDjango30Warning'

Tags: django, python-3.x, pycharm

Guys im fairly new to Django and I just started working on a personal project and decided that ill-use pycharm (i think its related to the error, or not).

when I run `python manage.py runserver`I get the error posted below. I did a bit of googling and looks like its caused by inconsistency with Django versions.

I currently have Django 3.0 and I checked both globally and in the venv.

I tried to start a project outside of py charm and im running into the same issue. idk what I need to do to start using Django again. Did anyone run into this? Is this because of pycharm? If so what can I do to fix the issue?

```
(venv) aiden@aiden-XPS-15-9570:~/PycharmProjects/NewsAggregator$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aiden/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aiden/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/aiden/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_static.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango30Warning
ImportError: cannot import name 'RemovedInDjango30Warning'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/aiden/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/aiden/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/aiden/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 395, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/aiden/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 382, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/aiden/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/aiden/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 76, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "/home/aiden/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/aiden/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/home/aiden/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/home/aiden/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/home/aiden/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/home/aiden/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/home/aiden/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 125, in get_package_libraries
    "trying to load '%s': %s" % (entry[1], e)
django.template.library.InvalidTemplateLibrary: Invalid template library specified. ImportError raised when trying to load 'django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_static': cannot import name 'RemovedInDjango30Warning'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment out the following line:

```
from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango30Warning
```

in the files below:

```
python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templatetags/admin_static.py
python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/templatetags/staticfiles.py
```

Comment: Manual edit in the Python packages' files? This can get you in trouble. I learnt to avoid doing this.

Comment: @Alexandru-MihaiManolescu It's perfectly fine to edit text files if the code they contain is broken. Regarding the issue, commenting out is fine, since the `RemovedInDjango30Warning` from `django.utils.deprecation` is doing nothing anyway, see the code https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/utils/deprecation.py, this class is removed in branch 3.0.x: https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/utils/deprecation.py

Comment: @mestia A reinstall of packages/dependencies will overwrite your changes and will bring back the old problems in the future. You should edit only your/your team's code.

Comment: In general I agree, but in this case it is a valid solution for a broken module. Once it is solved one can go to upstream and try to fix in the proper way. In fact I suspect that importing 'RemovedInDjango30Warning' will never be overwritten, since in is absent in the up to date django module.

Comment: what is a long term solution for this? this worked but i don't want to have to edit these files again on other computers. and why isn't it removed in 3.0? maybe i'm not understanding the purpose of this warning?

Comment: Most likely your local installation is broken, not Django itself. By editing site packages you are just providing a bandage that covers the real problem. Instead, we should dig deeper to find a better solution. My current hypothesis is that this error means that the Django installation is corrupt and that we should just `pip uninstall django` then `pip install django`. Editing `site-packages` directly is NEVER a good solution.

Comment: @MichaelDavidson `pip uninstall django` then `pip install django`. Specify a specific version when reinstalling if you wish. See my answer below.

Answer (score 11):

This is caused by conflicts in Django versions as seen here.

> ImportError: cannot import name 'RemovedInDjango30Warning'

Try uninstalling django

```
sudo pip uninstall django
```

and reinstall with a version lower than 3.0

```
sudo pip install django==2.2
```

**Edit**

If you wish to use different versions of Django you can use virtual environments.

First create a requirements.txt example from [here](https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/working-with-virtualenv-on-django-projects/)

> You can generate your project’s requirements by running the pip freeze
> command that lists all packages that are installed in your local
> machine with their versions.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

> Do note that this process can lead to certain unnecessary packages
> being written to the requirements file which are installed in your
> local machine but not required for the project. You must manually edit
> the requirements file in that case.

Then create your virtual environment

Step 1 install virtualenv

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Step 2 create virtual enviroment

```
virtualenv env
```

Step 3 Activate your environment

```
env\Scripts\activate
```

When you wish to deacitvate

```
deactivate
```

Step 4 Edit your requirements.txt to have the packages you'll need for your project.

Step 5 install requirements.txt (in same dir)

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Form infomation on deployment with mod_wsgi and Apache try [here](https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/working-with-virtualenv-on-django-projects/)

Comment: Thank you! I figured that Django must be too low so I was trying to figure out how to make it 3.0 even though it already was, did not cross my mind hat I need to do the opposite and downgrade.

Comment: i am unable to understand which type of conflicts and i don't want to reinstall lower version is there any other way to solve this problem

Comment: minor correction: step 5 should be `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: `pip uninstall django` then `pip install django` worked for me. In my case, I just wanted the most recent version. You can specify a specific version if you need to, though.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be from a corrupt Django installation in site-packages. Remove Django and install it again.

For me, I was upgrading an existing project from Django 2.2.6 to 3.1.7. It appears that somehow files from 2.2.6 were still hanging around. I had to run `pip uninstall django` twice to get back to a clean slate and then `pip install django` to install the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by django versions. You probably upgraded it.

If you do not want to go back to version 2, create a virtual environment and do pip install django==2.2

Answer (score 0):

this error depends on python,pip and django versions.This error comes on mostly running latest django version on python2.

install python3 version

use commands like

pip3 install django

python3 manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem.
this problem occur due to 2 version of python or django.
So, if you are running your project through virtual enviornment(venv), please check the python version in it.
By going in the following directly:

```
myproject/venv/lib/pythonx.y
```

please ensure that x.y is that version of python whichyou are using in your project.
Or if you are not running your project through venv, please check the python version your project is using and running on.

```
python --version
```

Answer (score 0):

I use django 4.1.4 and python 3.8.

```
pip3 uninstall django
rm ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/ -r
pip3 install django
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33479981)

Answer (score 0):

I had two different versions of the Django framework in my virtual environment (versions 2.2 & 3.2) . I had to run twice:

```
pip3 uninstall django
```

Then i reinstalled the framework:

```
pip3 install django
```

Answer (score -1):

i just wanna to say that when you have uninstalled django for some reasons, and when you  install it once again you will may appear the problem,just add 'class RemovedInDjango30warning:pass' in django/utils/deprecation.py that's it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).