# Upgrading to Django 3.0: 'django.contrib.admin.templatetags.admin_static': cannot import name 'RemovedInDjango30Warning'

Tags: python, django

My project was created with Django 2.2 and I would like to upgrade it to use 3. My problem is the same as [django error cannot import name 'RemovedInDjango30Warning'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59148185/django-error-cannot-import-name-removedindjango30warning?newreg=e8bba76bda4f4ffea43464c4f48c031e) . The accepted answer is to manually edit files in the Python packages which I don't think is a good practice(?). The other answers say to downgrade, so is there really no way to upgrade the project without creating it from scratch?

Comment: Have you checked the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/upgrade-version/) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file where that error is coming from has been removed in Django 3 (https://github.com/django/django/tree/3.0/django/contrib/admin/templatetags has no `admin_static.py`), so you might not have upgraded properly.

Try to delete your virtualenv and re-create it from scratch.

Comment: Ahh, thank you. It seems like I have several versions of Django installed (2.2.12, 2.2.6) before. And, when I `pip3 uninstall django`, it only uninstalled the last version.

Comment: Rather than delete your venv you can repeatedly run 'pip3 uninstall django', each time it will uninstall the highest version number.  I had 4 installed.